# How to update the dependency libraries (for example Apache collection libraries) in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I know that in order to get the latest version of Android/Google libraries, I can always go to the Android SDK Manager and update the Android Support Repository / Google Repository.

How about to update the other dependency libraries, such as the "commons-net:commons-net:20030805.205232" from Apache collection libraries? Since it is able to add these libraries from a Module's dependencies, I assume there should be a way to update it within the Android Studio IDE, but so far all the solutions I found is to download the specific .jar and put in the libs directory.

Just curious if anyone know there is a way to update these libraries from within the Android Studio IDE like the Android/Google dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android Studio & IntelliJ have a [dependency setting window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html) themselves. Though, it does not have a "update" feature as the SDK Manager does. Reason being: Updating a library can cause bugs, errors, or complete crashes in your app.

> so far all the solutions I found is to download the specific .jar and put in the libs directory

Not sure where you read that... [Remote Gradle dependencies](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html) are preferred in most cases.

> such as the "commons-net:commons-net:20030805.205232"

Go find what you want in Maven Central, find the most recent version, click the "Gradle" tab, the copy that into your build.gradle section.

There is no automated process for this, as far as I know, though you should be able to auto-complete version numbers via the IDE while you type it out.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you create a project under Android Studio, it generates for your **gradle files** which let you use dependencies. Gradle is like maven, you can find lot of documents on google.

Under "Project" tab -> Gradle Scripts -> build.gradle (Module app), you'll find something like this :

```
 dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.0.2@aar'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.4.0'
compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'}
```

So you just have to put your dependencies and gradle will download them for you.

[More here.](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html)